# Overfitting - huge difference between training and validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 180k images for which I try to recognize the characters on the images (License plate recognition). All of these license plates contain seven characters and 35 characters are possible, so the output vector y is of shape `(7, 35)`. I therefore onehot-encoded every license plate label.

I applied the bottom of the EfficicentNet-B0 model (https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function) together with a customized top, which is divided in 7 branches (because of seven characters per license plate). I used the weights of the imagenet and freezed the bottom layers of `efnB0_model`:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.2)(model)
    backbone = model

    branches = []
    for i in range(7):
        branches.append(backbone)
        branches[i] = Dense(360, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
        branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
        branches[i] = Activation("relu") (branches[i])
        branches[i] = Dropout(0.2)(branches[i])
              
        branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
    
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

For training and validating the model I only use 10.000 training images and 3.000 validation images due to the big size of my model and the huge number of data which would make my training very, very slow.

I use this DataGenerator to feed batches to my model:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

I fit the model using this code:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 32,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 32,
                    epochs = 10, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Now, after several epochs of training, I observed big differences regarding training accuracy and validation accuracy. I think, one reason for that is the small size of data. Which other factors influence this overfitting in my model? Do you think, there is something completely wrong with my code/model? Do you think the model is to big and complex as well or is it maybe due to the preprocessing of the data?

Note: I already experimented with Data Augmentation and tried the model without Transfer Learning. That leads to poor results on training AND validation data. So, is there anything what I could do additionally?

[image: accuracy]

Comment: Like you said, your model is VERY big. Training a model this big with such few datasets will easily cause over training as you have seen. More data is never a bad thing, just keep the batch size small enough to not overwhelm your GPU. You haven't stated whether you have used any image pre-processing either, which will help you in this case.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I updated the question. I use preprocessing (resizing them to (224, 224) and dividing the image values by 255). What else could I do? What is very strange to me: On GPU my model trains slower than on CPU.... What batch size would you recommend? And do you think there is a chnace to reduce the size of the model without loosing to much information?

Comment: Slower training on GPU compared to CPU can be attributed to a number of reasons, from compatibility to drivers. You can try reducing the number of dense layers to 2. I would recommend to train a network which finds the bounding box and crops the number plate and then using some other network/algorithm to identify the letters/numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I hope I will find a way to train the network on GPU efficiently. Reducing the dense layers is possible. Unfortunately I cannot switch to another method because I am trying to recognize the license plates via a segmentation-free approach for a studies project... What do you think about the batch size? Is 8 or 16 to small or too big?

Comment: try 10k train and 2k val ? maybe 1k is not enougth...
for performance problems, maybe try on Google collab : https://colab.research.google.com/
I recommend to try also a CNN :)

Comment: @Tobitor Will depend on your GPU, try and push the highest batch you can. 8/16 would be considered mini-batch which is a common technique but I think 8 is too small.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am using Google Colab's GPU. Do you have any experiences with it and maybe a recommendation regarding the batch size?

Comment: @SidoShiro92: I already use Colab and the CPU there, unfortunately training is very, very slow and inefficient. It's even slower than without using GPU there...

Comment: did you checked that  EfficicentNet-B0 training is correctly freeze ?

Comment: I think, it is correct: `efnB0_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efnB0_model.trainable = False`.` But now, it seems to work... I don't know why, but it is the first time the network is trained faster in GPU than on CPU... I did not change anything regarding the code...

Comment: What is the learning rate that you are using?

Comment: Also, why are you using this approach specifically for this task? Why not segmentation followed by recognition?

Comment: I am using the default learning rate `lr = 0.001`. I use this approach because in the last years the so-called segementation-free license plate recognition system was introduced, e.g. here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8078501 and https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-13-1733-0_6. Without the need to segment the license plates before recognizing its text an error source is eliminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First a disclaimer

Are you sure that this is the correct approach to follow? The EfficientNet is a model created for image recognition, and your task demands the correct localization of 7 characters in one image, recognition of each one of them, and also demand to keep the order of the characters. Maybe an approach of detection + segmentation followed by recognition like in [this medium post](https://medium.com/@theophilebuyssens/license-plate-recognition-using-opencv-yolo-and-keras-f5bfe03afc65) is more efficient (pun intended). Even though I think that this is very likely to be your real problem, I will try to answer your original question.

## Now some general tips regarding overfitting

There's a very good guide [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/) in Keras documentation on how to use EfficientNet for transfer learning. I will try to summarize some tips here.

From your question seems that you are not even doing the fine-tuning step which is essential for the network to learn the task better.

> Now, after several epochs of training, I observed big differences regarding training accuracy and validation accuracy.

With several, you mean how many epochs? Because from the image you put in the question I think that the second complete epoch is too soon to infer that your model is overfitting. Also, from the code (10 epochs) and for the image you posted (20 epochs) I would say to train for more epochs, like 40.

Increase the dropout. Try some configurations like 30%, 40%, 50%.

Data Augmentation in practice will increase the number of samples that you have. However, you have 180K images and are only using 10K of images, data augmentation is good but when you have more images available try using them first. From that guide I mentioned, seems that with this model and Google colab is feasible to use more images to train. So, try to increase the train size. Still in the topic of DA, some transformations may be harmful to your task, like too much rotation or reflection since you are trying to recognize numbers and letters.

Reducing the batch size to 16 may provide more regularization which helps to fight overfitting. Speaking of regularization, try to apply [regularization](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/) to the dense layers that you are adding.

### EDIT:

After quickly reading the paper you linked, I reaffirm my point about the epochs since in the paper the results are shown for 100 epochs. Also from the charts in the paper, we can see it's not possible to confirm that the author did not had overfitting too. Additionally, the changes in the Xception network are not clear at all. Changing the input layer has an impact on the dimensions of all other layers because of the way that the Convolution operation work and this is not discussed in the paper. The operations performed to achieve that output dimension is not clear too. Besides what you did I would suggest using a pooling layer to get the output dimensions that you want. Finally, the paper doesn't explain how the positioning of the plate is guaranteed. I would try to get more details about this paper that you are trying to reproduce to be sure that you are not missing anything in your model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer! I will try to apply these tips. What do you think about my approach using a segmentation-free license plate recognition system? Do you think my approach is theoretically correct?

Comment: Hey @Tobitor I've edited my answer after quickly reading those papers you linked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sure, we cannot exclude that the authors had problems with overfitting too. But as illustrated in Fig 4 they had a very high validation accuracy after only a few epochs. But I think you are right that I should get some more details about the paper, but that is not that easy... And yes, in a manner I try to reproduce the results but I use other data and another architecture (EfficientNet vs. Xception; top of the model in the paper is not clear).

Comment: I've been there, I know the struggle to reproduce some papers. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks! Since it is for my Master's degree, I hope it's coming to a good end :-)

Comment: Regarding your original post: with several epochs, I meant 10 epochs and had this huge differences between training and validation accuracy and validation accuracy did not increase significantly but bounces between 0.17x and 0.19x

Comment: If want to discuss this further I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218695/efficientnet-overfitting) for it

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on character detection + recognition problem for industrial application. From my experience using only deep CNN and dense layer to predict character class is not the best approach to solve this problem. There are good research papers for scene text recognition problem, one common approach to design character recognition problem is to have ---

1. any deep CNN model like VGG, ResNet or EfficientNet to extract the image feature.
2. Then add some RNN layers on top of CNN backbone to get character sequence from the extracted features. This would be a great plus if you want to predict variable length of character.
3. After getting character sequence from RNN layers, the next step is to decode this character sequence. For this you can either use [CTC based method](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Egraves/icml_2006.pdf) or [attention mechanism](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762). Both of these methods have their own pros and cons. CTC based methods are fast but performance is bit poor, on the other hand, attention based models give good results but they are very slow. So the selection of the method depends on your requirement.

Below image from very famous text recognition paper [CRNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05717v1.pdf) gives general idea about above steps.
[[image: Steps for text recognition from very famous research paper: CRNN ][2]]

For training the model, @Hemerson has given good suggestions. Try to build and train this type of model with multiple stages and I am sure you will get better results:)

Best regards!